# Linux write to serial port in c++ returns bad file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I am writing a c++ program to send a receive data from a device located at /dev/ttyACM0. I am able to read from the device without a problem, I can write to it from the command line, but I can not write to it within my c++ program. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include "SerialComms.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
SerialComms::SerialComms() {
    serial_filestream = -1;

    //CONFIGURE THE PORT
    //The flags (defined in /usr/include/termios.h - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/termios.h.html):
    //  Baud rate:- B1200, B2400, B4800, B9600, B19200, B38400, B57600, B115200, B230400, B460800, B500000, B576000, B921600, B1000000, B1152000, B1500000, B2000000, B2500000, B3000000, B3500000, B4000000
    //  CSIZE:- CS5, CS6, CS7, CS8
    //  CLOCAL - Ignore modem status lines
    //  CREAD - Enable receiver
    //  IGNPAR = Ignore characters with parity errors
    //  ICRNL - Map CR to NL on input
    //  PARENB - Parity enable
    //  PARODD - Odd parity (else even)
    tcgetattr(serial_filestream, &options);
    options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;     //<Set baud rate
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
}

bool SerialComms::Init(string type){
    //The flags (defined in fcntl.h):
    //  Access modes (use 1 of these):
    //      O_RDONLY - Open for reading only.
    //      O_RDWR - Open for reading and writing.
    //      O_WRONLY - Open for writing only.
    //
    //  O_NDELAY / O_NONBLOCK (same function) - Enables nonblocking mode. When set read requests on the file can return immediately with a failure status
    //                                          if there is no input immediately available (instead of blocking). Likewise, write requests can also return
    //                                          immediately with a failure status if the output can't be written immediately.
    //
    //  O_NOCTTY - When set and path identifies a terminal device, open() shall not cause the terminal device to become the controlling terminal for the process.
    if (type == "USB"){  //if type equals USB, open USB
        serial_filestream = open(USBSerial, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);      //Open in non blocking read/write mode
    }else if (type == "UART1"){
        serial_filestream = open(UART1, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);      //Open in non blocking read/write mode
    }

    if (serial_filestream == -1)
    {
        //ERROR - CAN'T OPEN SERIAL PORT
        printf("Error - Unable to open: %s\n", type.c_str());
    }else{
        printf("Opened serial type: %s\n", type.c_str());
    }
    tcflush(serial_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(serial_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);
    printf("Serial Comms for type: %s intialized", type.c_str());
    return 1;
}

bool SerialComms::Ping(){
    WriteSerial("p,1,1;\n");
    return true;
}

 char* SerialComms::ReadSerial(){
    if (serial_filestream != -1)
    {
        // Read up to 255 characters from the port if they are there
        char rx_buffer[256];
        int rx_length = read(serial_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);     //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
        if (rx_length < 0)
        {
            //An error occured (will occur if there are no bytes)
        }
        else if (rx_length == 0)
        {
            //No data waiting
        }
        else
        {
            //Bytes received
            rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
            int j = 0;
            while (rx_buffer[j] != ';' && rx_buffer[j] != '\0' && rx_buffer[j] != '\n'){
                j++;
            }
            char rx_return[j+1];
            for(int i = 0; i < j+1; i++){
                rx_return[i] = rx_buffer[i];
            }
            rx_return[j+1] = '\0';
            return rx_return;
        }
    }
    return '\0';
}

bool SerialComms::WriteSerial(string data_out){
    const char * tx_buffer = data_out.c_str();
    if (serial_filestream != -1)
    {
        int wr = write(serial_filestream, tx_buffer, strlen(tx_buffer));
        if (wr < 0){
            printf("Error writing to Serial: %s \n", strerror(errno));
            return 0;
        } else{
            printf("WroteSerial: %s, %d \n", tx_buffer, strlen(tx_buffer));
            return 1;
        }
    }else{
        printf("Error writing to Serial filestream errors \n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
SerialComms::~SerialComms() {
    close(serial_filestream);
}
```

If I use the command:

```
echo "p,1,1;\n" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

It works without a problem, and I receive back the expected data from the serial device.

However, my main loop in the c++ program calls the WriteSerial function once a minute like so:

```
void Ping(SerialComms serialLine){
    serialLine.WriteSerial("p,1,1;\n");
    printf("pinged at: %s \n", ctime(&now));
}
```

The first time the write is performed it doesn't give an error, but it doesn't seem to work, and the second write returns a bad file descriptor error. Also, it screws up reading from the port as well. Here is my program output:

```
WroteSerial: p,1,1;
, 7 
pinged at: Wed Dec 30 19:08:05 2015

Error writing to Serial: Bad file descriptor 
pinged at: Wed Dec 30 19:09:06 2015
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here so any suggestion would be appreciated. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic but I can't see it at the moment.

Comment: I see a common mistake here of assuming that if you call write() to write 10 bytes, for example, then write() will write 10 bytes. This is not true. See write()'s man page. write() may decide that only 5 bytes can be written at this time, and return 5. Especially since you're using O_NDELAY! When writing to a device file descriptor, and **especially** with O_NDELAY, you must always use poll() or select() to wait until the file descriptor is writable, before writing. Then, check if all bytes were written, if not then you must repeat poll()/select(), then attempt to write the remaining bytes.

Comment: P.S. When reading from an O_NDELAY file descriptor, you also must use poll()/select() before attempting to read from it, too.

Comment: You could try calling tcgetattr after you open the serial_filestream (i.e. in Init rather than the constructor).  You might be getting weird values in the termios structure by calling it for the garbage -1 file descriptor, and that could then mess up the real file descriptor when you call tcsetattr.  My only other suggestion would be to try calling cfmakeraw on the termios structure before calling tcsetattr - sometimes that resolves mysterious errors with serial devices.

Comment: Print the `serial_filestream` in both the messages `Error writing to Serial: …` and `WroteSerial: …` to check if it got overwritten, or use `strace -ewrite …`.